# Add index if it does not exist and copy nearest value

Tags: sas

I wish to add records to a dataset for every value of a certain id (`days`) from 1 to the minimum value of that id in a certain table, by groups of another variable (`date`), and with the same value for another variable which the minimum id record has (`rate`). Most likely my explanation is not very clear, please have a look at the following example.

I have the following dataset `myrate`

```
     date   days   rate
02JAN1996      5   5.76
02JAN1996     10   5.81
02JAN1996     15   5.41
03JAN1996      6   5.76
03JAN1996     12   5.75
03JAN1996     13   5.74
```

And my intended result is as follows

```
     date   days   rate
02JAN1996      1   5.76
02JAN1996      2   5.76
02JAN1996      3   5.76
02JAN1996      4   5.76
02JAN1996      5   5.76
02JAN1996     10   5.81
02JAN1996     15   5.41
03JAN1996      1   5.76
03JAN1996      2   5.76
03JAN1996      3   5.76
03JAN1996      4   5.76
03JAN1996      5   5.76
03JAN1996      6   5.76
03JAN1996     12   5.75
03JAN1996     13   5.74
```

I am really clueless - I have pictured solving this with a macro, which finds the smallest `days` for each by group and outputs the necessary lines. But I cannot translate this idea to code. Additionally, I assume there is an easier way to do this with a data step.

Edit: I believe I can solve this with PROC IML but I also assume that is not the most efficient way.

Comment: Honestly the IML solution I can imagine is much more complicated than the brute force data step solution (not to mention the much cleaner data step solution using `first` like Dmitry uses) - if there's an elegant IML solution i'd love to see it.

Comment: Hey @Joe, thank you for your help again (and sorry for the "fluff" in the post, I thought this was good etiquette). I have added an answer with a PROC IML solution - This was way less efficient than the solution provided below. Nevertheless, it was good exercise for me to try and come up with an alternative. Perhaps there is a way to improve it. I wouldn't qualify it as elegant, sadly, but I believe it does its job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done as follows:

```
proc sort data=myrate; by date days; run;
```

**UPDATED** as per Joe's comment:

```
data want;
  set myrate;
  by date;
  if FIRST.date then do;
    do days=1 to days;
       output;
    end;
  end;
  else output;
run;
```

Comment: You actually don't have to use i, I believe you can simply say `do days=1 to days;` thanks to how the compiler works.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works very well. Following @Joe comment about PROC IML, I added another solution - which is incredibly less efficient than yours.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is way, way, way more efficient than the following code for my dataset.  however, following @Joe's comment, I tried to develop the solution I thought of with PROC IML.

Nevertheless, here is what I used:

```
proc iml;
    use myrate;
    read all var{date days rate} into mymatrix;
    unique_rows = uniqueby(mymatrix,1,1:nrow(mymatrix));
    do i=1 to nrow(unique_rows);
        if mymatrix[unique_rows[i],2] ^= 1 then do;
            currdays = mymatrix[unique_rows[i],2];
            h = J(currdays-1,1,mymatrix[unique_rows[i],1]) || (1:currdays-1)` || J(currdays-1,1,mymatrix[unique_rows[i],3]);
            mymatrix = insert(mymatrix,h,unique_rows[i]);
            unique_rows = unique_rows + currdays - 1;
        end;
    end;
    create want from mymatrix;
    append from mymatrix;
    close want;
quit;
```

For a dataset with 15,979,017 observations and 4452 by groups, this code took:

```
PROCEDURE IML used (Total process time):
real time           8:59.22
cpu time            8:59.50
```

While the Data step above took:

```
DATA statement used (Total process time):
real time           2.95 seconds
cpu time            2.22 seconds
```

Which proves my solution is not good. Perhaps there is a better way to use PROC IML or to improve my code.